# State of each widget in ListView.builder is affecting each other. How to differentiate widgets in ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, listview, animation, key, state-management

I am building an app that has gmail type animation in which when the circular avatar button is clicked the List tile gets selected with a rotation animation.
[image: Pic of animation 1]

[image: Pic of animation 2]

The list of items are built using **ListView.builder**. But when the circle avatar of a list item is clicked it affects the **whole list** of items and rotates every circle avatar. From similar questions asked I changed Listtile into a separate stateful widget as every item could hold its own state. But this doesn't change the output.

I didn't get the output even after using keys(Unique and object). I am stuck here for a long time but couldn't figure what and how to do it. Is there any way to differentiate widgets in Listview.builder and maintain their states seperately?
Alternatively when I use checkbox/selectable icon its holding the state for each item induvidually.

````
class MailList extends StatefulWidget {
  int index;
  List<MailModel> account;
  Animation rotationAnim;
  AnimationController circleAvatarController;
  OneShotAnimation riveAnimationController1;
  OneShotAnimation riveAnimationController2;
  List<int> selectedIndexes = [];
  UniqueKey key;

  MailList({
    required this.index,
    required this.account,
    required this.rotationAnim,
    required this.circleAvatarController,
    required this.riveAnimationController1,
    required this.riveAnimationController2,
    required this.selectedIndexes,
    required this.key
  }):super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _MailListState createState() => _MailListState();
}

class _MailListState extends State<MailList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      child: Dismissible(
        key: ValueKey(widget.index),
        child: GestureDetector(
          key: ValueKey(widget.index),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15.0),
            child:  Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: widget.account[widget.index].isSelected ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2): null
              ),
              height: 70,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: AnimatedBuilder(
                          builder: (context, child){
                            return Transform(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                key: ValueKey(widget.index),
                                backgroundColor: widget.account[widget.index].isSelected ? widget.account[widget.index].defaultOnSelectedColor : widget.account[widget.index].senderInfo.profileColor.withOpacity(0.75),
                                child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
                                  tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1),
                                  builder: (context, double anim, child){
                                    return widget.rotationAnim.value > 90 &&  widget.account[widget.index].isSelected
                                        ? Opacity(
                                          child: Icon(
                                            widget.account[widget.index].defaultOnSelectedIcon,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          opacity: anim,
                                        )
                                        : Text(
                                        widget.account[widget.index].senderInfo.senderName[0].toString(),
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 21.0,
                                            color: Colors.white
                                        ));
                                  },
                                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              transform: /*isSelected(widget.index) ? (Matrix4.identity()
                                ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                                ..rotateY((widget.rotationAnim.value) / 180 * math.pi))
                                  : (Matrix4.identity()
                                ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                                ..rotateY(0 / 180 * math.pi))*/
                              Matrix4.identity()
                                ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                                ..rotateY((widget.rotationAnim.value) / 180 * math.pi),
                            );
                          },
                          animation: widget.circleAvatarController,
                        ),
                        onTap: (){
                          selectUnSelect(widget.index);
                          widget.account[widget.index].isSelected = !widget.account[widget.index].isSelected;
                          widget.account[widget.index].isSelected ? widget.circleAvatarController.forward() : widget.circleAvatarController.reverse();
                          setState(() {

                          });

                        },
                      )
                    ],
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  widget.account[widget.index].senderInfo.senderName,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: widget.account[widget.index].isSeen
                                          ? FontWeight.normal
                                          : FontWeight.bold
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                    "10:00"
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          widget.account[widget.index].title,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.5,
                              fontWeight: widget.account[widget.index].isSeen
                                  ? FontWeight.normal
                                  : FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  widget.account[widget.index].content,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: widget.account[widget.index].starred ? Icon(
                                    Icons.star,
                                    color: Colors.orange[300],
                                  ):
                                  Icon(
                                      Icons.star_border
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    widget.account[widget.index].starred = !widget.account[widget.index].starred;
                                  });
                                },
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: (){

          },
        ),
        background: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: dragWidget(
                left: 8.0,
                controller: widget.riveAnimationController1
            )),
          ],
        ),
        secondaryBackground: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 8.0
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 50.0,
              child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                "assets/gmail_drag_anim.riv",
                controllers: [
                  widget.riveAnimationController2
                ],
                animations: [
                  "Animation 1"
                ],
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                //antialiasing: false,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onDismissed: (direction){
          widget.account.removeAt(widget.index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  bool isSelected(int index){
    return widget.selectedIndexes.contains(index);
  }

  selectUnSelect(int index){
    if(isSelected(index)){
      widget.circleAvatarController.reverse();
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 320), (){
        widget.selectedIndexes.remove(index);
        setState(() {

        });
      });

    }else{
      widget.selectedIndexes.add(index);
    }
  }

  Widget dragWidget({
    double? left,
    double? right,
    required OneShotAnimation controller
  }){
    return Container(
      alignment: right != null ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: left != null ? left : 0.0,
            right: right != null ? right: 0.0
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          child: RiveAnimation.asset(
            "assets/gmail_drag_anim.riv",
            controllers: [
              controller
            ],
            animations: [
              "Animation 1"
            ],
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            //antialiasing: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```



// ListView.builder:

SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (context, index){
                          return MailList(
                              key: GlobalKey<_MailListState>(),
                              index: index,
                              account: account1_mail_data,
                              rotationAnim: rotationAnim,
                              circleAvatarController: circleAvatarController,
                              riveAnimationController1: _riveAnimationController1,
                              riveAnimationController2: _riveAnimationController2,
                              selectedIndexes: selectedIndexes
                          );
                        },
                        childCount: account1_mail_data.length
                    ),
                  )
````

Comment: Just a comment: I can not see the widget where ListView is used. My guess is: are you giving controllers as an argument while building these items?  So maybe you are giving the one-only controller set to all items. So all your items in listview are using the same controller.

Comment: @SuatÖzkaya thanks for your comment. There is some mistake in copying, only the first line of stateful widget is missing in code (MailList) only the state(_MailListState) of it is present. In terms of controllers, there are separate controllers for all animations I hope. But the question is how differentiate each widgets built using the builder?

Comment: I mean: currently, you have a controller in the parent widget and pass the same controller as an argument for all widgets while building, this is like passing the same callback function to all children, so if one of the children triggers something then all children are affected. Try to create controllers inside the 'MailList'. Example: What happens if you create and use only one TextEditingController for all the TextFields in a Column? Anything you type in one of them affects all others.

Comment: @SuatÖzkaya ya I have given the same controller for every widget. But the other controllers(Rive Animation Controllers) perform their tasks properly without overlapping each other. Only circle Avatar animations overlap each other. Do you have any suggestions to assign different controllers for every widget? or to differently maintain the states of each widget? I have an idea: Can I make circle avatar a separate widget that maintains its own state so that the animation can be done separately